# String in php session

Tags: php, session

How i can put string in a session?

for. e.g. : `$_SESSION_[$questioncounter+'question'] = $accepted;`

if `_$questioncounter = 2_`, this mean `$_SESSION_['2question']`

Comment: create an array instead then just push it inside, the question number and the status (accepted)

Comment: PHP string concatenation is done with the `.`. Also, it's `$_SESSION`, not `$_SESSION_`

Comment: You may store an array into $_SESSION so there's no need to concatenate strings. Sounds weird to me ;) Why not using this approach `$_SESSION['question'][5] = TRUE;` having in mind your case.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `.`(dot) to concat string and variable and remove `_` from  `$_SESSION_` try

```
$_SESSION[$questioncounter.'question'] = $accepted;
```

so full code :-

```
<?php
session_start();
$questioncounter = 2;
$accepted = 'yes';
$_SESSION[$questioncounter.'question'] = $accepted;
echo $_SESSION['2question'];  // yes
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes concatenation is needed but not in this case. Building variables by concatenating strings in this case would be the worst approach.

This is the way you should do things

```
// start session
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

// now, add your questions to the $_SESSION this way
$question = array('Is the sky really blue?', 'Should I stay or should I go?', 'Why I can\'t fly');
$_SESSION['question'] = $question;

// or this way
$_SESSION['question'][0] = 'Is the sky really blue?';
$_SESSION['question'][1] = 'Should I stay or should I go?';
...

// add their status this way
$_SESSION['question'][0]['accepted'] = 1; // or $_SESSION['question'][0]['status'] = 1;
$_SESSION['question'][1]['accepted'] = 0;

// and finally use them like this
echo $_SESSION['question'][0];

// or
if($_SESSION['question'][0]['accepted']){
    // say 'Bravo!'
}
```